# Unable to Edit "About Me" with any Content

Tags: support, profile-page

I have been unable to edit the "About Me" section of my *Stackoverflow* profile for a few weeks now. When I try to save it, I get the following error:

```
Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
* can't save your About Me field with that content.
```

Presently I'm trying to change the wording of the English text. I wonder if maybe it's rejecting the multi-lingual content? I have also tried re-saving the current content, but that produces the same error.

I have tried this on Chrome 46.0.2490.71 and Firefox 37.0.1 (both on Linux).

There is a [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196240/i-am-getting-the-message-cant-save-your-about-me-field-with-that-content-whe) question about this same error message, but it dates to **two years ago**.

Comment: Not sure (since I can't test it), but perhaps it's rejecting CJK characters due to recent spam. Otherwise, what language were you trying to add? *Edit* it seems so...

Comment: Not trying to add any languages. My intent is to leave the Chinese text as is and modify the English text. I'm assuming the site uses UTF, so language shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If only content-blockers would be so kind as to mention what exactly they're having trouble with. But that would make it too easy for actual spammers/people with malicious intent to game the system. As a test, what if you change a single letter (say remove the comma after management) and try to save, are you blocked then too? - edit crud, I missed that you already tried saving the same content. So it is indeed the current content that is the problem and not what you're changing it to.

Comment: Yes, CJK characters are currently blacklisted due to a recent spam-wave

Comment: Blocking entire languages is a terrible way to deal with spam. I'm sure other sites have better ways of dealing with this. It isn't an acceptable solution, either for SO or for users.

Comment: If you're going to block an entire langue on spam grounds couldn't a rep threshold be set so only low-rep accounts are blocked, or something similar?